# Thumbnail image for original picture

Tags: android, ios, image

I have a mobile app which has a screen with list of small images (3x3 grid). Click on image takes user to detail screen, where user can see that image in original size. Now, problem is that, for now, on backend side i only store full sized images (which i know is bad), but when i retrieve images for list i would like to return thumbs for original sized images.
The question is - what is the recommended thumbnail size to return?
Consider that this is an iOS and Android app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on your needs ...I would choose something from 0.5 to 1 of the widget size in pixel. By widget i mean control where you wana show the image.

Comment: actually the biggest concern is on the backend side, images are processed there

Comment: you can always pass size as prameter (fx `https://example.com/givemeimage?id=1199&size=128`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how big you want to show it to the user.
i personally prefer 256X256